# How to extract numbers inbetween characters in R

Tags: regex, r

I have different character vector containing strings like `"p.L86*"`, `"p.A59fs*4"`, `"p.E309*"`, etc. Each have different digits. I only want to extract the first a few numbers between the characters, so the expected solution would be `86, 59, 309`.

I tried `gsub("[^0-9]+","","p.A59fs*4")`, but it will save all digits...

Comment: For the first match, use `sub()` instead of `gsub()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sub` to get the first match results:

```
x <- c('p.L86*', 'p.A59fs*4', 'p.E309*')
sub('\\D*(\\d+).*', '\\1', x)
# [1] "86"  "59"  "309"
```

Or fallback to the **stringi** package and match them instead:

```
stri_extract_first_regex(x, '\\d+')
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was about to post.  Nice to know I'm doing it right.

Comment: And also `sub("\\D+(\\d+).*", "\\1", x)` ... I think?

Comment: Yes that would work as long as there are characters before the first set of digits.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(v1, '(?<=[^0-9])\\d+(?=[^0-9])')
#[1] "86"  "59"  "309"
```

Or using `sub`

```
sub('^[^0-9]+([0-9]+).*', '\\1', v1)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("p.L86*", "p.A59fs*4", "p.E309*")
```